# Android apkanalyzer, invoked by command line, gives a "NoClassDefFoundError" exception

Tags: java, android, apk, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to run the apkanalyzer tool provided by Android SDK (under Sdk/tool/bin), but I am not able to make it work. I know that I can also use this tool through AndroidStudio, but I need to automate the apk analysis to cover a lot of APKs. So, I followed this https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apkanalyzer to use it.

Anyway, when I try to launch apkanalyzer (e.g. apkanalyzer apk summary APKname.apk) it gives the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
>       at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
>       at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
>       at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
>       at com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli.getAaptInvokerFromSdk(ApkAnalyzerCli.java:277)
>       at com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli.main(ApkAnalyzerCli.java:129)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
>       at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>       ... 5 more

Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you resolve it? I'm having the same error.

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not figure out what was the problem. I just did the analysis that I needed by hand, by writing a little program that unpackages the APKs and extracts the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. All I had to do was set the JAVA_HOME correctly.
I set the JAVA_HOME in my bashrc to $PATH_TO_ANDROIDSTUDIO/jre

my exact statement in ~/.bashrc:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/rahul/Softwares/android-studio/jre
```

Sample for Mac users:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [Android Studio 4.2 runs with java 11 instead of java 8](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#4.2-bundled-jdk-11), you might also notice this error upon your Android Studio upgrade if you are pointing `JAVA_HOME` toward your AS bundled jdk. ([See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55436585/fix-sdkmanager-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-batchfile?rq=1))

To recover:

1. Download jdk 8 yourself (https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html)
2. Find out the 1.8 JAVA_HOME path (/usr/libexec/java_home -V on mac)

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    15.0.1, x86_64: "OpenJDK 15.0.1"    <path to have home1>
    1.8.0_291, x86_64:  "Java SE 8"     <path to have home2>
```

3. Run the following:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre"
```