# Fix sdkmanager java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError batchfile

Tags: java, android, batch-file

I get an error trying to run `sdkmanager`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 5 more
```

How can I fix this as I have tried changing to Java 7, 8 and 10, but none is working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Android sdkmanager to run with Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076422/getting-android-sdkmanager-to-run-with-java-11)

Comment: i was specific: 7,8,10. anyway the issue was solved way back in time.

Comment: My issue was specifically a freak issue with build-tools 33.0.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/68430992/332578

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this solution

First open `sdkmanager.bat` with any text editor

Then find this line

```
  %JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%
```

And change it to this line

```
  %JAVA_EXE%" %DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS% --add-modules java.xml.bind %JAVA_OPTS% %SDKMANAGER_OPTS%
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: What folder is that file in?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it's under `android SDK folder/tools/bin`

Comment: Note: using `--add-modules` should work up to Java 10, but anything Java 11 or later will not. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/28037

Answer (score 11):

I had the issue as default installation of java was v11

`java -version`
Should be : `openjdk version "1.8.0_252"`

Fix:
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`
Don't worry won't overwrite
Then switch to the correct version via
`sudo update-alternatives --config java`

confirm correct output from `java -version`

than run `sdkmanager` again.

Comment: if you have “Could not find or load main class java.se.ee" after then run JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions'

Comment: This solution works for me on Ubuntu 20.10. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I had to do the following to fix this error on Windows 10:

1. Install JDK 8. I had JDK 12 installed but it did not seem to work with that version.
2. Add Java to my environment variable Path

To add Java to your environment variable Path do the following:

`Go to Computer -> Advanced system settings -> Environment variables -> PATH -> and add the path to your local java bin directory. It looks like this: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-versionyouhave\bin`